# ssh session stuck after some time of iddleness

Tags: ssh, bash, fedora

I'm using fedora 19 and bash 4.2.53(1)-release

If I leave an ssh connection opened for some minutes and don't do anything with it, the terminal get stuck.

Here's netstat's output:

```
tcp        0   1440 x.x.x.x:port       x.x.x.x:port        ESTABLISHED 3596/ssh
```

So it seems that after some time the traffic just stays in the send queue and never leaves.

Any idea why? or what system tool/log should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your client's config:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

This will send a no-op every 60 seconds, which will hopefully prevent your firewall from discarding its state tracking entry for your SSH session.

Comment: Seems to be working! Is that also working of ssh session into another ssh session (ssh-ception)?

Comment: No, that's not what it's doing.

Comment: each client - server pair have their own configuration I guess then. i.e I could time out on a session if I only configured my first client/server1 pair to send nops, and not the second one (client on server1/ server2)

Comment: You can make that directive global to your client config, so it applies to all connections.

Comment: Hmmmm.. I have trouble understanding how the client configuration on my laptop can impact the ssh client on the machine I'm logged in.

Comment: This needs to be set in the client configuration of whatever ssh client you're using.